# Is there a DLNA enabled media player for Android?

Tags: media-player, dlna

Is there a DLNA compatible media player app available for Android?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but see also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/can-i-get-dlna-on-my-droid

Comment: There are a lof of DLNA players for Android. You have to search for DLNA in play google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UPnPlay](http://www.appbrain.com/app/upnplay/cx.hoohol.silanoid) is an Alpha release and apparently still a bit glitchy, but still some positive reviews.

Answer (score 5):

try twonky https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pv.twonkyremote

Comment: Does it also work as a client?
I am interested in watching movies stored on my pc on my android device...

Comment: yes but your server needs to transcode certain files such as .mkv

Comment: This software is LOVELY!
I just need to find a good server on the pc side...
I saw that Windows Media Player works fine on Windows 7 side... I'd like to use Xbmc but I had no luck: Can't see the library of it from phone.

Answer (score 3):

A similar question exists on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682430/android-developing-plugins-for-media-sharing (For which I gave the info I was aware of)

Answer (score 2):

All Share is an app on samsung phones that plays & downloads DLNA media from a DLNA server.  All Share can also be used to play files of the phone onto a DLNA device, or stream files from a DLNA server via the phone then play back on a 3rd DLNA device.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into [2player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twoplay.twoplayer) and it seems to work well (not great thou).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Skifta](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skifta.android.app). It will play files from DLNA server in any player installed on your device. Also it can be a media server and controller. The description says the app is DLNA Certified.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [MediaHouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dbapp.android.mediahouse), UPnP/ DLNA Browser with [Plex Media Server](http://www.plexapp.com/) (get the beta with DLNA) on my home computer and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need an UPnP controller, like [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp) and an player (e.g. [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad)). That's all what's need to stream via UPnP. At least it works well for me with [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/).

Answer (score 0):

[uPNP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid&hl=en) works perfectly for me for streaming. I use the stock video / Mobo video alongside that and have been able to stream anything I've put on my server.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I've used Sklift and some other DLNA apps.But Now I'm using [ArkMC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arkudadigital.arkmc.gm&hl=en) because it let me to stream photos and 1080p videos Flawlessly.