# Can I get DLNA on my Droid?

Tags: dlna

Can I get DLNA on my Droid 1 through some sort of hack, patch or accessory or do I just have to upgrade to a newer phone?

I'm sure this question must seem absurd to some people but I looked around and it's still not clear to me if DLNA is a software or hardware solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get DLNA"? That's not an acronym I'm familiar with.

Comment: DLNA stands for "Digital Living Network Alliance" which is the working group that is making the way these devices talk to each other for sharing media but I think it's also used to refer to the actual capability (which I haven't figured out if it's hardware based or software based). I was complaining to someone at the Verizon store about the lack of hdmi out on the Galaxy S and he replied, "you don't need it, it has DLNA." I think it is basically some kind of protocol to use wifi to connect media devices, Phone to TV, computer to TV... There site is vague enough to confuse the hell out of me.

Comment: DLNA isn't only for wifi. Basically it's about sending media between different devices in a network. It's a software thing, if you can get your devices on the same ethernet. :)

Comment: Are you after a DLNA client or server for your phone? In other words do you have content on your phone that you want to play on a TV (or PC) or do you have content on a PC that you want to play on your phone?

Comment: Both if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Twonky](http://www.twonky.com/) media, who make the very good Twonky DLNA server for PCs, have released a [Twonky Server app for Android](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-pv-tms-ptmm.aspx), this should allow you to share content (videos, music, pictures) that are stored on your phone to network attached DLNA compatible devices on your network (eg Windows Media Player on Windows 7, XBox 360, PS3, specialised set-top boxes, some new TVs).

Also, I don't know if it's carrier specific but my Samsung Galaxy S came with the AllShare app (which I haven't used yet) that claims to be a DLNA server and client. Can't find it in the Market, so I assume its Samsung only.

Comment: What about non samsung phones? I'm really happy using Twonky but I'd like to see movies stored on my pc on my android device...

Comment: @Pitto if you're looking to play the files on your phone, the you probably want one of these two linked questions: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/dlna-enabled-media-player or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-android-phones-play-dvd-format-movies-over-wifi

Comment: It seems that the Twonky Server app  is no longer in the Android market as a free app.  But the functionality seems to be included in Twonky Mobile, which requires a license after a free trial period: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pv.twonkyremote  A "Screen Share" function from Twonky is part of the "Media Room" that comes with e.g. the HTC MyTouch 4G Slide and it also requires a license.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed you were complaining about the lack of HDMI out on your Galaxy S? Samsung make a [micro-USB to HDMI-out cable](http://www.clove.co.uk/samsung-galaxy-s-i9000-microusb-to-hdmi-cable) specifically for the Galaxy S. The linked page is a UK reseller, but I can't believe that it's not available from Samsung in the US, or Us based resellers?

Comment: I might be mistaken about the model of phone we were talking about. Either way I was just trying to give some background.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Skifta](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skifta.android.app). It will play files from DLNA server in any player installed on your device. Also it can be a media server and controller. The description says the app is DLNA Certified.