# What can I do with DLNA on an android smartphone?

Tags: dlna

What can I do with DLNA on an android smartphone?

I understand it allows wireless streaming media, but beyond that I have trouble finding details.

Will DLNA enabled smartphones receive data from servers? Will I be able to hit "play" on my smartphone and listen to it on my DLNA enabled stereo?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/dlna-enabled-media-player

Comment: Also see this question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/can-i-get-dlna-on-my-droid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Android phone with DLNA should be able to both send and receive.  My Galaxy S uses an app called AllShare to manage it, and there are others like 2Player in the Market. I'm sure you could stream to your stereo.

Comment: Learend some more.  DLNA has more than one standard.  Many devices are DLNA certified, but they need to be DLNA "Play To" certified if you want to stream from your phone to your device.

Comment: You're right but for an android device, it is the app that needs to be able to playback, control or stream. For other DLNA devices, the software inside can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This app from Qualcomm uses DLNA to play your media from your phone: http://www.appbrain.com/app/skifta-beta/com.skifta.android.app

Comment: Found a great video about Skifta today that explains a lot of what DLNA on a smartphone can do: http://phandroid.com/2011/02/03/skifta-brings-first-readily-available-dlna-certified-app-to-market-froyo/

Answer (score 1):

DLNA-enabled TVs, for example, can be used as an external monitor without HDMI or any cables. I want to show my large family my vacation pics on my phone but the screen is too small for all of them to see at once. My TV should be Wi-Fi enabled and DLNA-certified and I should have a wireless router too, obviously.

- Connect my phone and TV* to the same Wifi network coming from the same router.
- Using the brand appropriate "device media sharing" program<sup>**</sup> on my phone and TV I connect them to each other.
- Now I select the video, picture or music file to play and it will be play through my home Wifi network to my TV and maybe vice versa. So everyone can enjoy at once.

<sup>*</sup>The same can be done with a DLNA enabled music player or anything.

<sup>**</sup>Media appropriate app can be found by searching up on Google or Youtube or any other search engine.